# What should I make out of this message?

Tags: macos, ruby, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to set up the Ruby on Rails on my Mac OS X Maverick just to check whether I have Rails installed I typed

```
 rails --version
```

and I got this as response

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0 /universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:212: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
```

Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

Should I go ahead and use the install command ? Would It would be safe or there is a better way to do this thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Rails tries to tell you is that your `/usr/local` directory should not be world-writable (i.e. writable to everyone and every process ever logging in to/running on your system).  It's what the last three digits in `040777` tell you.  It's an octal-number (base 8) representing a bit-mask of permissions where

```
777
||` permissions for everyone
|`- permissions for group the directory is owned by
`-- permissions for the user the directory is owned by
```

and

```
1 - execute permissions (entering for directories)
2 - write permissions
4 - read permissions
```

`7 = 4 + 2 + 1`, meaning all permissions for user, group and others (a.k.a. world) set.

You should do `chmod 0755 /usr/local` to fix the permissions to user-writable only.

Comment: First of all thanks Andreas. One question after doing this will it be perfectly okay to install rails using "sudo gem install rails" command. What if I have installed Homebrew would it be better to install through Homebrew

Comment: I'm not using OS X, thus I don't really know what exactly Homebrew does.  Personally I prefer installing Ruby-stuff with `gem`, but I really can't tell you whether it's the better idea to do so on OS X. :(

Comment: Fine just wanted to know if I go ahead and install using this command "sudo gem install rails" it wont be any issue.